# Font rendering different in Chrome than in Firefox; Myriad rendering as Gill Sans

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, stack

I'm using Myriad Pro on my site (by client's specifications, it is absolutely crucial to use Myriad), and it was rendering correctly until all of a sudden a few days ago, the way it rendered changed on Chrome. It still looks right on Firefox and other browsers.

This is how it is supposed to look:
[image: 1]

This is how it's rendering on Chrome: 
[image: 2]

This is the font stack I'm using:

```
font-family: "Myriad Pro", "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, sans-serif;
```

Is there another way I can use Myriad that won't cause this issue? What is the problem, and how can I make it look right on Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

I just found this link in the google products forum https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/bkFBZbeMklk/xztRA14qcdwJ

This issue has been escalated to Google Chrome Team \o/

Meanwhile, you can perform this step to solve the problem:

```
   -Open Chrome.
   -Go to address bar and type chrome://flags/#disable-direct-write and press ENTER.
   -Now, click on "Disable" and restart Chrome.
```

Also:

```
-Close Chrome
-Go to Desktop
-Click on Chrome shortcut with right button and click "Properties"
-In field "Target" type space and after add /high-dpi-support=1 /force-device-scale-factor=1
```

Must be like this, for example: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" /high-dpi-support=1 /force-device-scale-factor=1
    Now, save the changes and try start Chrome

Also:

```
-Type chrome://settings/search#hardware in your address bar and press ENTER
-Uncheck the box "Use hardware acceleration when available" and restart Chrome."
```